# Pydev does not integrate Django in eclipse?

Tags: python, django, windows, eclipse

I have installed eclipse and pydev and django. When I open the command line I see:

```
C:\Users>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 4, 2, 'final', 0)
>>>
```

Therefore django is correctly installed.

When I create a new django project in eclipse I get:

[image]

an empty project with no manage.py ect.

I want to have a full configed django project when I create one in eclipse!

Whats wrong with my Python installation?

I appreaciate your answer!!!

**UPDATE:**

Right now my pythonpath looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This post http://lowcoupling.com/post/47845431628/creating-a-new-django-project-with-eclipse-py-dev provides a complete tutorial. I hope it could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of settings you need to ensure you have before the Django integration will work, (also, the pydev integration requires your project to be in a src folder before things like autocomplete will work afaik.)

Two good guides for setting up PyDev and integrating Django:

[PyDev setup](http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html)

[PyDev Django setup](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html)

Comment: The main things that are needed are to configure your interpreter, make sure that you are USING that interpreter when you create your project, make sure you are creating (or converting to) a django project, and that you are adding your src folder to the PYTHONPATH when you create your project. Both those guides have a step-by-step to setting up a new project, so it might be an idea to setup a new project and then once you understand how it works, apply it to your existing project

Answer (score 0):

Nothing important, but if you've install Eclipse just to code Django websites, you may have a look at [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/), which is an Eclipse IDE with PyDev and extra stuff. Not much configuration needed, might be good for later.